# Помощь с Calback_query_handler в aiogram 2.9

Tags: python, aiogram-2.x

Возникла проблема с Callback в aiogram 2.9

При нажатии на inline-кнопки ничего не происходит.
Ниже код:

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor
from aiogram import types
from aiogram.types import Message, CallbackQuery
import config

bot = Bot(token=config.token, parse_mode='HTML')
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

@dp.message_handler(commands="start")
async def start(message):
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    button = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Кнопка', callback_data='first_button')
    keyboard.add(button)
    await message.answer('Нажмите на кнопку', reply_markup=keyboard)

@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda callback_query: True)
async def some_callback_handler(c: CallbackQuery):
    await c.message.edit_text('Вы нажали на кнопку')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=False)
```

В логах пишется это:

```
DEBUG:aiogram:Make request: "getUpdates" with data: "{'timeout': 20}" and files "None"
```